# SiC surface reconstruction

Tags: software-recommendations, surfaces, vesta

I know how to cleave surfaces with integer Miller indices, however I wonder how I could cleave a $(\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}) R30$ reconstruction of $(001)\,\, 4H-SiC$.

I have found a nice link to O-lattice theory here,
https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_7/backbone/r7_3_1.html
but I thought there might be a script out there for this purpose.

I am currently trying my chances with VESTA!

Thank you for your help,
Roozbeh

Answer (score 5):

The reconstructed $(\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3})R30$ surface unit cell can be obtained by first applying the rotation matrix

$ \begin{pmatrix}    1.0 & 2.0 & 0.0 \\   -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 \\    0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0  
 \end{pmatrix}$

to the primitive bulk unit cell, and then the reconstructed $(001)$ surface can be cleaved from this unit cell, or the other way around.

top view of the primitive
[image]

and reconstructed surface
[image]

Cheers, Roozbeh